# What are options for viewing site analytics from my iPhone/Android/Blackberry?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, iphone, mobile, android

Currently we use Google Analytics and there are a number of iPhone apps for viewing the data.

What other options are there?

Are there analytics platforms that have good mobile versions of their sites?

Or one that just has really good adoptions/apps for all major smart phones?

I would also be curious to know what apps people are using for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Ego](http://ego-app.com/) might be just what you are looking for. Then you have:

1. [Analytics App](http://analyticsapp.com/)
2. [myAnalytics](http://www.iphone-myanalytics.com/)
3. [Cracklytics](http://escoz.com/cracklytics/)